# How to set current item value conditionally using Java streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

To simplify my problem assume I have a list of strings while converting these string to integers I may encounter `NumberFormatException`, from the element I get this exception I need to mark all the successor elements as failed once. Is there a better way to pass the state of the previous element or improve this code?

```
  AtomicBoolean isInvalidRequest = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  list.stream().map(ele -> {
      if (!isInvalidRequest.get()) {
        try {
          Integer.parseInt(ele);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          isInvalidRequest = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        }
        return ele;
      } else {
        return "invalid previous element";
      }
    });
```

Given a list of elements `List("1", "2", "A", "4", "3")`

Excepted Output of elements `List("1", "2", "A", "invalid previous element", "invalid previous element")`

### Edit

As mentioned this is a simplified version of my actual problem. In the actual problem, my failure is HTTP POST call, I need to fail all the consequent elements from the element I get an error response.

Comment: Try fold and build up a LinkedList one by one maybe?

Comment: I understand this is a simplification of your actual use case, but do you need to use Java streams and AtomicBoolean? For the example you've provided, a simple for-each loop and flag would work.

Comment: why would you need to store everything after the failed item? isn't the index of the failed one enough?

Answer (score 1):

It’s a strange requirement to alter the elements after the invalid one. The consequences are that there is no change at all when only the last element is invalid.

Normally, you would be interested in the index of the first invalid element, e.g.

```
OptionalInt firstInvalid = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(ix -> {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(list.get(ix));
                return false;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return true;
            }
        })
        .findFirst();
```

Then, if you truly want to alter the list in the described way, you can use

```
firstInvalid.ifPresent(ix ->
    list.subList(ix+1, list.size()).replaceAll(s -> "invalid previous element"));
```

Note that this separation of concerns makes the code more efficient. The search for the first invalid index is short-circuiting, returning after the first invalid element has been found, instead of dealing with the subsequent elements. Setting the subsequent elements to the predefined value then happens unconditionally. When all elements are valid, the first step has to check all of them, but then, the second step is skipped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code snippet

```
AtomicBoolean isInvalidRequest = new AtomicBoolean(false);
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("A");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("5");
    boolean val = false; 

    List<String> newList =  list.stream().map(ele -> {
     if(!isInvalidRequest.get()) {

    try{
      Integer.parseInt(ele);
      return ele;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      isInvalidRequest.set(true);
      return "string wrong";
    } 
     } else {
       return "previous string wrong";
     }
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

   newList.stream().forEach(ele -> System.out.println(ele));
```

The output was

```
1
2
string wrong
previous string wrong
previous string wrong
```

But keep in mind that changing the state or having side effects from inside a map function is not a good idea. So you may want to change that.